# How to redirect all urls with file extension to a differen page in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Please everyone, I am trying to prevent direct access to all files and pages in my application, and also to ensure that no one can determine what particular language the site is written in.

So, I want a situation where calls to myapp.com/path/to/page.php, whether it exists or not, internally redirects to myapp.com/page_not_found.php. And similarly, myapp.com/path/to/anywhere redirects to myapp.com/index.php.

I have been able to handle the later using
If the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ index.php?path=$1&sub=$2 [QSA,L]
```

But for the former, I don't have any idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect *.php to /page_not_found.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ /page_not_found.php [R]
```

If you want to redirect other file types, like say *.asp, change (php) to (php|asp).

To redirect everything else, add this too:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php [L]
```

As a note here, you don't need to pass in the path as a get parameter (i.e. index.php?path=$1...). Instead, from within PHP, read the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value instead. This stops your original query string from getting messed up (i.e. you can use $_GET as normal). So for example if the original request is `myapp.com/path/to/page?id=1` then `$_GET['id']` will continue to work as normal and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `/path/to/page?id=1`.

Note that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` can contain a query string so you'll want to split at `?` to chop that off:

```
// Grab the path:
$path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Split at ? to remove the query string if there is one:
$path=explode('?',$path,2);

// Get the first part only:
$path=$path[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, @LukeBriggs, for your answer. Although I already got help somewhere else before you posted this, but your solutions does the job perfectly. Sorry I didn't report earlier. Thank you.